# Calculating distance between two classes of latlong points

Tags: r, coordinates, spatial

I have a series of latlong coordinates in R which are divided among two individuals:

```
name   lat         long
A      -28.63784   28.69085
A      -28.65366   28.70843
A      -28.80918   28.94223
B      -26.71335   22.80713
B      -26.75022   20.58426
B      -34.37791   20.51215
```

How do I calculate the distance between the coordinates of one individual to the other but not to itself? I've looked at similar questions on here but I can't see anything that will do the grouping for me.

Thanks

Comment: have a look in gis.stackexchange: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140272/calculate-distance-between-a-set-of-points-lat-and-long-in-qgis-or-r

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First create two lon/lat data frames, one for individual `A` and one for `B`:

```
locationsA <- subset(d, name == "A", select = c("long", "lat"))
locationsB <- subset(d, name == "B", select = c("long", "lat"))
```

The [rdist.earth](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/fields/docs/rdist.earth) function in the fields package can then compute the matrix of distances of all pairings:

```
library(fields)
dists <- rdist.earth(locationsA, locationsB)
```

For the six rows you showed, for example, these distances are (in miles):

```
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
[1,] 384.1700 513.2758 624.3275
[2,] 385.5346 514.5599 624.4023
[3,] 402.4771 530.8293 628.1450
```